# dart ffi gen with multiple dynamic libraries

Tags: dart, ffi

I'm trying to create Dart bindings for [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl).  GSL needs **two** dynamic libraries `libgsl.so` and `libgslcblas.so`.  I have used ffigen to generate the bindings and things work fine as long as all symbols called are all from `libgsl.so`.

But there are issues when BLAS related functionality is needed that is available from `libgslcblas.so`.  For example, there is a function `gls_blas_dnrm2` which exists in `libgsl.so` that needs function `cblas_dnrm2` from `libgslcblas.so`.  So when I call the generated method for `gsl_blas_dnrm2` (which is resolved correctly) I get the error

```
/usr/lib/dart/bin/dart: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libgsl.so: undefined symbol: cblas_dnrm2
```

which makes sense as the symbol `cblas_dnrm2` is in `libgslcblas.so`.

I've tried to modify the ffigen generated lookup to look in both libraries, something like this

```dart
  Gsl((ffi.DynamicLibrary, ffi.DynamicLibrary) dynamicLibraries) {
    ffi.Pointer<T> aux<T extends ffi.NativeType>(String symbolName) {
      print('looking up symbol $symbolName');
      if (dynamicLibraries.$1.providesSymbol(symbolName)) {
        return dynamicLibraries.$1.lookup(symbolName);
      } else if (dynamicLibraries.$2.providesSymbol(symbolName)) {
        return dynamicLibraries.$2.lookup(symbolName);
      } else {
        throw StateError('No symbol $symbolName');
      }
    }

    _lookup = aux;
  }
```

but that doesn't help because the `_lookup` function does not get called for the `cblas_dnrm2` at all.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

From C I can simply do

```
gcc -Wall -o example example.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

and things work.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I've documented the steps [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/228).

Thanks to the Dart FFI team member Daco Harkes for the gentle nudging along the way.